# Convergent series, by comparing ratios ($\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \le \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that if a sequence eventually increases less than another sequence, then if the infinite sum of the second sequence converges, so must the infinite sum of the first sequence. More formally:

Let $x_n >0 $ and $y_n >0$ for all $n∈\Bbb N$. Suppose that for some $N∈\Bbb N$ we have $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \le \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}$ for all $n \ge N$. Show that if $\sum y_n$ converges, then so does $\sum x_n$.

I have made some progress. Clearly $(y_n) \to 0$ and I've used this to show that $(x_n) \to 0$, though I know that's insufficient. I've been told that the best way is to find a way to bound $x_n$, but so far I've only been able to do that in terms of $x_{n+1}$ by noting that $\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}$ is bounded because it converges, which isn't very helpful.

Interestingly, this seems to be a reasonably useful result: comparing ratios of series to show series convergence, but I haven't found it referenced anywhere, so is this perhaps a trivial special case of some more general test?

Thank you

Comment: Show by induction that for all $h\geq 0$, you have $x_{N+h}\leq \frac{x_N}{y_N}y_{N+h}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can rearrange this inequality as
$$
x_{n+1}\leq \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}x_n\leq\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}\frac{y_n}{y_{n-1}}x_{n-1}\leq\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}\frac{y_n}{y_{n-1}}\frac{y_{n-1}}{y_{n-2}}x_{n-2}\leq\cdots.
$$
This tells you, in particular, that for any fixed $m<n$, for any $k\in[m,n]$ we have
$$
x_k\leq\frac{y_k}{y_m}x_m,
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}x_k\leq\sum_{k=m}^{n}\frac{y_k}{y_m}x_m=\frac{x_m}{y_m}\sum_{k=m}^{n}y_k.
\end{align*}
$$
Because the terms are all positive, you can use this inequality to show that whenever $\sum y_k$ is Cauchy, so is $\sum x_k$.

Comment: I did make that assumption - the first sentence of the formal statement?

Comment: Ah, quite right.  Just missed it :-)

Comment: But this is great thank you :) how did you think to multiply by 1 ($\frac{y_i}{y_i})$ like that please? EDIT: sorry not multiply by 1, but combine inequalities in that way?

Comment: It's just by applying the inequality again.  We know (by replacing $n$ by $n-1$, say) that $x_n\leq\frac{y_n}{y_{n-1}}x_{n-1}$.  And so on.